# Unable to display Stats under server management

Tags: orientdb

We are using 2.1.11 DB in Standalone server (no distributed/cluster).
When I go to server management window and click server stat, I see 0 in CPU/RAM/Disk.

Error log shows: `Command not found: GET.distributed/stats [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]`

How can I resolve this?

```
0 CPU 0 RAM 0 DISK
Status: AGENT NOT FOUND Ops/Sec: 0
Active Connections: 0Network Requests: 0
Average Latency: 0Warnings:
```

Comment: Are you using community or enterprise edition?

Comment: Community edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server Management->Server Stat works in enterprise edition only

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12222735)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that this IS an answer because it does explain why he is `Unable to display Stats under server management` and so it responds to `How can I resolve this?`.  Doesn't it?

Comment: I agree.  However, your answer was flagged by the system as low quality.  During the review process I did not click through to the question, I doubt many people do for one-liner answers.  I attempted to bulk it out a bit in the edit - feel free to edit it again.  Your answer was in fact concise and not low quality :-)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply